# Why does my cycles preview cause my PC to freeze

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Whenever i switch to the rendered view my whole PC freezes every so many seconds is there something not right in blender or is my PC just not up to it anymore?

Comment: Even with the default scene?

Comment: Even with the default scene yes. My PC is roughly four years old now so i do believe it might be time for a upgrade?

Comment: Is the whole pc freezed or just Blender's window? Since wich Blender's version did you experienced this problem? Are you using CPU or GPU? The average-4-years PC should be able to handle the default scene

Comment: Im using GPU render i will switch to the render preview it still work for about three seconds before freezing around about ten seconds and so on and so on.

Comment: How does it respond to CPU? GPU might have issues IDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your CPU/GPU can't handle Cycles.

Cycles samples the scene as fast as it can, I think your computer freezes while trying to sample the scene:
[image] (You can find this at the top of the 3D view.)

I suggest trying a simpler scene and seeing if it stops freezing on that one. If it doesn't, I would believe there might be a problem with your CPU/GPU or it is not supported by Cycles.

It may just be a problem with having the wrong computing device selected. If you have a supported GPU you can select it under User Pref > System:

[image]

And then selecting GPU under the rendering tab:

[image]

And if that still doesn't work, try selecting the CPU instead.

And if all that fails, I recommend getting a better GPU/CPU. You can compare and find the best one for your price here: http://olivieramrein.com/2012/02/25/blender-cycles-best-hardware-using-the-benchmark-spreadsheet-analysis/

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this, and in my case it has been caused by having 5x View-mode subdivision on a UV sphere. Probably not what caused it for you, but this info might help someone else.